# Need help rewriting a foreach and do until loop

Tags: vb.net, foreach

So i am trying to recode this because its not working correctly :

> ```
> Private Sub StartTrafficExchange()
>
>     Dim downloadstring As New StreamReader(Response2.GetResponseStream())
>     Dim filterstring As String() = downloadstring.ReadToEnd.Split("|")
>     For Each stirngman As String In filterstring
>         linklist.Items.Add(stirngman)
>     Next
>
>     Do Until linklist.Items.Count = 0
>         Dim rand As New Random
>         linklist.SelectedIndex = rand.Next(0, linklist.Items.Count - 1)
>         Dim strimgna As String = linklist.SelectedItem
>         Dim newlinkstring As String() = strimgna.Split("``")
>         For Each stringma As String In newlinkstring
>             If stringma.Length < 8 Then
>                 GoTo a
>             Else
>                 LabelX1.Text = "Navigating To " + stringma
>                 stringma = stringma.Replace("[TIER4]", "")
>                 Debug.WriteLine(stringma)
>                 WebKitBrowser1.Navigate(strimgna)
>                 Thread.Sleep(15000)
>             End If
>             LabelX1.Text = "Navigating To " + stringma
>             ProgressBarX1.Value += 1 a:
>         Next
>         linklist.Items.Remove(linklist.SelectedItem)
>     Loop
>     ProgressBarX1.Maximum = linklist.Items.Count
>     ProgressBarX1.Value = 0
>     StartTrafficExchange()
> End Sub
> ```

So what does the code do ? Well it fetches a webrequest to a link where the source will be like

```
http://www.asdfd.com``[TIER4]|http://aesde.com``[TIER4]|http://www.excaedf.com``[TIER4]|
```

As you can see the above code first splits "|" and adds them each to a list.
Then we split other things to make it as a perfect url and then navigate to it by webkitbrowser... and waits 15 sec by using thread.sleep (Idk if it works.) then removes it from linklist in a foreach and do until loop. So whats the problem ? Well it doesn't work correctly the webkitbrowser is just hanging .

Note : The sub StartTrafficExchange() is called when the form loads.

Can someone tell me whats wrong with the above code and is there anyother way to make this work ?

-Thanks-

Comment: Its because of your Thread.Sleep() your webkitbrowser is freezing

Comment: There seems to be a lot of very similar string processing to split the array multiple times, when once would do nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `linklist` is not an actual `LinkedList` but is really a `List(Of T)` or the list of a List control, you can replace this chunk of code:

```
    Dim filterstring As String() = downloadstring.ReadToEnd.Split("|")
    For Each stirngman As String In filterstring
        linklist.Items.Add(stirngman)
    Next
```

with this:

```
Dim filter As String() = downloadstring.ReadToEnd.Split("|")
linklist.AddRange(filter)
```

which does the same thing, only faster, and with less memory being consumed.

Next, move this way up (like immediately after the `AddRange`):

```
ProgressBarX1.Maximum = linklist.Items.Count
```

I was going to type out why to make the various changes, but here is the whole routine as I would refactor it:

```
Private Sub StartTrafficExchange()
  ' Performing one split here that removes everything that needs
  ' to go will be faster, take less memory, won't have to be
  ' touched as many times
  Dim filter As String() = downloadstring.ReadToEnd.Split("``[TIER4]|")
  linklist.AddRange(filter)

  ' Set your maximum value so it knows when it is full
  ProgressBarX1.Maximum = linklist.Items.Count

  ' Create a counter to let us know how many items 
  ' have been processed
  Dim counter As Int = 0
  Dim currentURL As String = String.Empty

  Do While linklist.Items.Count > 0
    ' Get the current URL from our list
    currentURL = linklist.Items(counter)

    LabelX1.Text = String.Format("Navigating To [TIER4] {0}", currentURL)
    LabelX1.Refresh() ' Allow the label to update

    ' This is only good if you have a debugger turned on
    ' or are running from the IDE
    Debug.WriteLine(currentURL)

    WebkitBrowser1.Navigate(currentURL)

    ' Not a good idea as it will block the UI
    ' from responding. If you need a delay that
    ' doesn't appear to lock up the UI, implement
    ' a timer in a loop
    Thread.Sleep(15000)

    ' Increment the counter, then update the progressbar
    counter += 1
    ProgressBarX1.Value = counter
    ProgressBarX1.Refresh() ' Allow the progressbar to update
  Loop

  ' When you are through getting all of the URLs,
  ' clear the list just one time
  linklist.Items.Clear()

  ' Make recursive call to this sub
  ' You should limit the number of recursions
  ' somehow so you don't run out of stack space
  StartTrafficExchange
End Sub
```

If you want to pause the process with blocking the UI, use this:

```
' Create a new timer object that will run for 1/10 of second
Dim timr As New Timer(100)

' Run this for 150 times at .1 seconds will
' give you a 15 second pause and still leave
' the UI responsive
For iLoop As Integer = 0 To 150
  ' Start the timer for .1 seconds
  timr.Start()

  ' This tells everything on the form to process updates
  DoEvents()
Next
```

Comment: Thanks mate. But can you say me how i can implement timers in a loop ?

Comment: Just did. Check out the updates. Replace this one line `Thread.Sleep(15000)` with the lower example code.

Comment: Than using the timer in a loop cant it be dim timr as new timer(15000) ?

Comment: You could, but it would effectively be the same thing as the `Thread.Sleep(15000)`. You need the short time period to run `DoEvents()` to allow the application to handle anything else that might be going on at the same time.

Comment: Try changing Timer to System.Timers.Timer in the Dim statement.

Comment: thanks for the reply mate. I am actually a newbie to vb.net and i guess i messed up on something now :(. Can you view the total code through "teamviewer" mate ?

Comment: i guess it wont take more 5mins.. So please ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not very important but the code is inconsistent, you are using `C#` practices but you are in `VB.NET`, then remove all those `+` operator on strings appends and replace them with an `&`.

Second, if your purpose is to wait for the webpage to be fully loaded then using `Sleep` method is not the way, you need to suscribe to like an `WebBrowserDocumentCompleted` event of the browser control (I don't know the exact event name for a `WebKitBrowser`)

You can simplify things by writting a method called `NavigateAndWait` and use it instead of using `WebKitBrowser.Navigate` method.

I give you an example for a default `WebBrowser` control:

```
Private WebPageLoaded As Boolean = False

''' <summary>
''' Navigates to an url and waits the page to be loaded.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="url">Indicates the url to navigate.</param>
''' <param name="newWindow">Indicates whether the url should open into a new browser window.</param>
Private Sub NavigateAndWait(ByVal Browser As WebBrowser,
                           ByVal url As String,
                           Optional newWindow As Boolean = False)

    Me.WebPageLoaded = False

    AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowserDocumentCompleted
    Browser.Navigate(url, newWindow)

    Do Until Me.WebPageLoaded
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    RemoveHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowserDocumentCompleted

End Sub

' WebBrowser [DocumentCompleted]
Private Sub WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    Me.WebPageLoaded = True
End Sub
```

And other for a `GeckoFX` webbrowser:

```
Private WebPageLoaded As Boolean = False

''' <summary>
''' Navigates to an url and waits the page to be loaded.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="url">Indicates the url to navigate.</param>
Private  Sub NavigateAndWait(Byval Browser as Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser,
                             Byval url As String,
                             Optional loadFlags As Gecko.GeckoLoadFlags = Gecko.GeckoLoadFlags.None,
                             Optional referrer As String = Nothing,
                             Optional postData As Gecko.GeckoMIMEInputStream = Nothing)

    Me.WebPageLoaded = False

    AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf GeckoWebBrowserDocumentCompleted
    Browser.Navigate(url, loadFlags, referrer, postData)

    Do Until Me.WebPageLoaded
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    RemoveHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf GeckoWebBrowserDocumentCompleted

End Sub

' GeckoWebBrowser [DocumentCompleted]
Private Sub GeckoWebBrowserDocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Me.WebPageLoaded = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but in my case i shoudnt only wait until the site loads but should wait about 15-20 seconds.